# How to fix this amsmath warning about redefining \vec

Tags: amsmath, incompatibility

I am using the pss(b) template, which starts with,

```
\documentclass[pss]{wiley2sp} % provides pss two-column style
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{bm}              % uncomment these two packages if you
%\usepackage{w-greek}         % need extended greek-letter functionality in math mode
```

I always got this warning:

> Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine math accent `\vec`.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 59):

load `amsmath` first:

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\documentclass[pss]{wiley2sp} % provides pss two-column style
...
```

Then `amsmath` defines the `\vec` at first and `wiley2sp` will redefine it.

Comment: Your answer was flagged as too short. Could you edit and give some more information? Thanks.

Comment: This also fixes a similar problem with the llncs document style. Many thanks   (:

Comment: Great! solved my problem again :)

Answer (score 21):

This "problem" is inherent to the class you're using.

Here's what's happening: You load [`wiley2sp`](http://arxmliv.kwarc.info/sty/wiley2sp.cls), which sets up the document structure. It also (re)defines the macro `\vec`:

```
\if@mathematic
   \def\vec#1{\ensuremath{\mathchoice
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\displaystyle\mathbf{#1}$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\textstyle\mathbf{#1}$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptstyle\mathbf{#1}$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptscriptstyle\mathbf{#1}$}}}}
\else
   \def\vec#1{\ensuremath{\mathchoice
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\displaystyle#1$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\textstyle#1$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptstyle#1$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}}}}
\fi
```

This will print `\vec{<stuff>}` in **bold** math font. Yes, it actually redefines the macro from a former `\mathaccent` to the above.

Now you load [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), which cycles through a number of math accents and reconfigures them. Here's an extract from the actual code:

```
\def\@tempa#1{\@xp\@tempb\meaning#1\@nil#1}
\def\@tempb#1>#2#3 #4\@nil#5{%
  \@xp\ifx\csname#3\endcsname\mathaccent
    \@tempc#4?"7777\@nil#5%
  \else
    \PackageWarningNoLine{amsmath}{%
      Unable to redefine math accent \string#5}%
  \fi
}
\def\@tempc#1"#2#3#4#5#6\@nil#7{%
  \chardef\@tempd="#3\relax\set@mathaccent\@tempd{#7}{#2}{#4#5}}
\@tempa{\hat}
\@tempa{\check}
\@tempa{\tilde}
\@tempa{\acute}
\@tempa{\grave}
\@tempa{\dot}
\@tempa{\ddot}
\@tempa{\breve}
\@tempa{\bar}
\@tempa{\vec}
```

The above code is prefaced by the following documentation:

We redefine the standard math accent commands call `\mathaccentV`, using the mathgroup/encoding-number information embedded in their previous definitions. If the definition of an accent command does not have the expected form, we leave the accent command alone, but give a warning.

You'll notice the set of redefinitions require the former definition of the math accent to start with `\mathaccent` (as part of the `\ifx` condition in `\@tempb`). Since `wiley2sp` redefined `\vec` to mean something completely different (not a `\mathaccent` anymore), `amsmath` reports the warning.

A way around this would be to capture the definition of `\vec` *before* `wiley2sp` redefines it, and restore it before `amsmath` checks to redefine it. The following achieves this:

```
\let\oldvec\vec% Store \vec in \oldvec
\documentclass{wiley2sp}
\let\vec\oldvec% Restore \vec from \oldvec
```

Note that, if this is a publisher-related style or class, they most likely want their `\vec`tors printed in a specific format. So, removing this formatting of `\vec`tors is probably not advised.

Comment: It seems that this way can go around the problem. But it has new problem:`! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.9 \usepackage
               {color}
?` Here are my codes: `\let\oldvec\vec% Store \vec in \oldvec
\documentclass[pss]{wiley2sp} % provides pss two-column style
\let\vec\oldvec% Restore \vec from \oldvec
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}% Include figure files
% \usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{color}`

Comment: Looks like it complains the packages I used below amsmath.

Comment: @user2045447: Drop the `[dvips]` option for [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx). It will figure out what driver you need based on the compilation sequence. For example, if you are using `pdflatex`, you can't use `[dvips]`.