# \dot{\vec{\hat{x}}}} fails to compile with svjour3

Tags: vector, sv-classes

The title says it all. I would like to typeset the time-derivative of a vector whose symbol shall be `\hat{x}`. The documentclass svjour3 is used in Springer journals. The following MWE reproduces the behaviour in the article class:

```
\documentclass{article}
\if@mathematic
   \def\vec#1{\ensuremath{\mathchoice
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\displaystyle\mathbf{#1}$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\textstyle\mathbf{#1}$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptstyle\mathbf{#1}$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptscriptstyle\mathbf{#1}$}}}}
\else
   \def\vec#1{\ensuremath{\mathchoice
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\displaystyle#1$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\textstyle#1$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptstyle#1$}}
                     {\mbox{\boldmath$\scriptscriptstyle#1$}}}}
\fi

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \dot{\vec{\hat{x}}}  % Failure
    \vec{\dot{\hat{x}}}  % OK
    \dot{\hat{\vec{x}}}  % OK
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Pdflatex output contains

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\macc@adjust ->\dimen@ \macc@kerna 
                                   \advance \dimen@ \macc@kernb \kern -\dimen@
```

How can I typeset such a vector in the svjour3 class?

Comment: The code as posted has `\if@m` which tests if `@` is `m` so it is always false.

Comment: Where is that `if@mahtematic` even coming from? And why does your mwe use `article` but you talk about `svjour3`?

Comment: The code posted runs without error and the warning `Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine math accent \vec.
`

Comment: I figured that not everybody has access to the class svjour3 thus I copied the vector definition into an article in order to construct a mwe.

Comment: @user1225999 but you need to check that your "mwe" is actually an example of the problem, the above code clearly is not.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The posting clearly states that the code reproduces the behavior in an article class.

Comment: @user1225999 that's what its says but that statement is false, if you run the example you will see that you get no error so it is not an example of the problem.

Comment: @user1225999 I should say that making an example with a standard class rather than a publisher one is helpful, (I wish more did it:-) but it is only helpful if you copy enough of the code that the example is an _example_ otherwise it's just an `article`class document that doesn't have a problem which doesn't really help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry - I got my wires crossed... put the line with the comment `Failure` before the lines with the comment `OK` then it fails to compile. Things get more and more weird...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `svjour3` class uses a wrong way for redefining `\vec`.

Just load the class and do

```
\let\vec\mathbf
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\vec\mathbf % fix svjour3 wrong definition

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \vec{\dot{\hat{x}}}
    \dot{\vec{\hat{x}}}
    \dot{\hat{\vec{x}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer bold italic vectors, add `\usepackage{bm}` and do

```
\let\vec\bm
```

instead.

Comment: I assume the author of the svjour3 class had his/her reasons to define the vector this way. In what way does your definition behave differently?

Comment: @user1225999 I can see no good reason in defining `\vec` that way. The only reason I see is: let's port this code from a very old version of LaTeX to the new version, changing `{\bf#1}` into `\mathbf{#1}`.

Comment: @egreg -- it seems that your example shows up a bug (haven't tracked down where).  the middle "x" really shouldn't be italic; it should be bold and upright like the other two.  (but not your fault.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Math accents in `amsmath` should be revised.

Comment: @egreg -- true, but an `amsmath` overhaul hasn't been scheduled, and probably won't be soon.  i think i'll suggest that the maintainer of `mathtools` do it there as a "temporary" expedient.

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251672/45962

The cleanest way to do it is:

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\documentclass{svjour3}
```

Like that, amsmath is loaded first and defines `\vec`, then `svjour3` can redefine the command.

Unfortunately, you have to put the `\vec` into the outermost braces:

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\documentclass{svjour3}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \vec{\dot{\hat{x}}} %OK
    %\dot{\vec{\hat{x}}} %Failure
    %\dot{\hat{\vec{x}}} %Failure
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this will actually solve the problem in the question, as that problem is caused by the definition in `svjour3.cls`, as I understand it.

Comment: First, it did in my case. Second, like this, you don't have to redefine '\vec{ }' as the other solutions did.

Comment: So if you try the example at https://bitbucket.org/snippets/torbjornt/ayyMb it compiles without error? That is not the case here, but it works fine after uncommenting the `\let` statement. (Admittedly, the error I get is not the same as reported in the question.)

Comment: I tried your example. I have to admit, that it does NOT compile.
However, if you put the arguments in this exact order: `\vec{\hat{\dot{x}}}` it does. I'm sorry, i'll edit my answer.

Comment: Fair enough, so that's one more combination that works, but the combination that the OP wants to use is different -- the dot on top of the hat.

Comment: I just realized that. I edited my post accordingly. Should I delete my answer? I am not sure, whether it provides any further insight in the issue.