# `svjour3` `\vec` redefinition

Tags: packages, amsmath, journal-publishing, journal

I am having issues with `svjour3` the document is below. When I try to compile, I keep getting (and probably plenty more will come):

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty|105 warning| LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmr/m/n' in size <9.5> not available size <9> substituted
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty|| Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine math accent \vec.
|51 warning| LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <9.5> not available size <9> substituted
|51 warning| LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmtt/m/n' in size <9.5> not available size <9> substituted
frontmatter.tex|| Package mathptmx Warning: There are no bold math fonts on input line 13.
|| LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences up to 0.5pt have occurred.
```

What do I have wrong (how to handle the vector symbol and the fonts?)?

```
\documentclass[smallcondensed,final,natbib]{svjour3}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% for type 1 fonts in math environment
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[sumlimits,intlimits]{mathtools}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}% Chemical elements and equations
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}% general table environments
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% extending the color package
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}% to make the large data table in landscape mode
\usepackage{afterpage}% for the large data table
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}% Control layout of itemize, enumerate, description
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \title{my title}
    \author{me}
    \institute{someplace somewhere}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        bla bla bla
        \keywords{nothing interesting}
        \PACS{1234}
    \end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer helps you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102508/31034

Comment: Do `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` instead of loading `mathptmx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `\vec` made by `svjour3` is painfully wrong: it essentially does `\mathbf`, but in a very slow way.

Also `mathptmx` is a legacy of the olden times when there were very few fonts available. Use `newtx` instead.

Just undefine `\vec` before loading `mathtools` and redefine it later in a more sensible way. If you want bold italic for your vectors, load also `\usepackage{bm}` (after `mathtools`) and do `\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}`.

In order to avoid the spurious warning about size substitutions, load `fix-cm`.

```latex
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallcondensed,final,natbib]{svjour3}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\let\vec\relax % nullify the horrible definition of \vec
\DeclareMathAccent{\vec}{\mathord}{letters}{"7E} % restore the standard

\usepackage[sumlimits,intlimits]{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}% for type 1 fonts in math environment

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}% Chemical elements and equations
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}% general table environments
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% extending the color package
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}% to make the large data table in landscape mode
\usepackage{afterpage}% for the large data table
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}% Control layout of itemize, enumerate, description
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} % like Springer likes

\begin{document}
    \title{my title}
    \author{me}
    \institute{someplace somewhere}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        bla bla bla
        \keywords{nothing interesting}
        \PACS{1234}
    \end{abstract}

This is a vector $\vec{v}$.

\end{document}
```